# There was an error uploading the file, please try again!Error Code:6

Tags: php, windows, plesk

We have a website using **PHP 5.2** and it is hosted in **Windows Plesk** Server. We are now having issue in uploading any files via PHP. When we try to do so we are getting following error.

```
 There was an error uploading the file, please try again!Error Code:6
```

upload_tmp_dir  has local value "C:\Inetpub\vhosts\xxxxxx.xxx\httpdocs\tmp" and master value "C:\Windows\Temp" .

Can anyone suggest what should be the permission of these folders or do we need to check something else to fix this upload issue via PHP?

Here are the scripts I have used to test the Upload.

**Script 1**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Upload your files</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data"  method="POST">
    <p>Upload your file</p>
    <input type="file" name="uploaded_file"></input><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload"></input>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
<?PHP
  if(!empty($_FILES['uploaded_file']))
  {
    $path = "newupload/";
    $path = $path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $path)) {
      echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']). 
      " has been uploaded";
    } else{
        echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!Error Code:". $_FILES['uploaded_file']["error"];;
    }
  }
?>
```

**Script 2**

```
<?php
echo '<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="uploader" id="uploader">';
echo '<input type="file" name="file" size="50"><input name="_upl" type="submit" id="_upl" value="Upload"></form>';
if( $_POST['_upl'] == "Upload" ) {
 if(@copy($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['file']['name'])) { echo '<b>Upload SUKSES !!!</b><br><br>'; }
 else { echo '<b>Upload GAGAL !!!</b><br><br>'; }
}
?>
```

Script 1 gave the error "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!Error Code:6" . Script 2 showed upload success. But uploaded file was missing.

Comment: There are two major problems here. (1) That is not a PHP native error; that's generated by whatever PHP code you are running. Without seeing that code, it's very hard to help you. *If* that error code is taken directly from the `$_FILES` superglobal, then it [corresponds to `UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR`](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php), meaning your temporary directory doesn't exist or has a permissions problem.

Comment: (2) PHP 5.2 is truly ancient. It was released more than 12 years ago and has been at end of life -- not even getting security updates -- for [almost 8 years](http://php.net/eol.php). Even the final version (5.2.17) has [dozens of known vulnerabilities](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-74/product_id-128/version_id-106044/PHP-PHP-5.2.17.html). You *really* need a plan to upgrade to [at least 7.1](http://php.net/supported-versions.php).

Comment: I have tested the upload using two scripts. I will edit the question with those details also. Please do check.

Comment: I have edited question and added more details.